# How to get hardware info from a client remotely

Tags: hardware, info

Before i say anything i want to inform you that: My Programming skills are 0 My Linux knowledge is very basic

I am trying to find a way to get hardware information remotely and store them in my linux server which is just a desktop with a linux distribution. Let me explain the main idea. We have one desktop with linux distribution. This is going to be the Linux Server.Can be any distribution. This Linux Server is connected to a 48Port Switch. Then from the switch i have 48x ethernet cables that i am about to connect simultaneously 48 desktops. I configure desktops to boot in pxe. After i plug in the ethernet cable in every desktop(client) a GUI pop-up with several options. The GUI will interact with the server. It can be php coded with 2-3 basic options. Nothing special.

Step No1, 1st Option - BIOS Update In the Linux server there will be a directory with sub-directories for every model of desktops. For example HP 6200,HP 8200, HP 8300 etc etc Each subdirectory will contain the BIOS files from the manufacturers site. After the client machine boots in pxe and the gui pop-up, the technician choose to make bios update. There is a drop down menu to choose model. What happens here: the client request from Linux Server to execute remotely BIOS update. The server sends via ftp the choosen bios files (that the technician choosed at drop down menu) and the process of bios update installation starts through network. My machine has now the latest BIOS version.

Step No2, 2nd Option - Get Hardware Info There is a option "Get Hardware Info", after technician choose it and press ok, what happens here: The client request from Linux Server to execute remotely the following: 1. LSHW commands (I configure what combination of lshw/parameters will run) 2. HDSentinel portable application (for HDD quality test, health etc etc) HDSentinel is a hdd testing software. 3. Smartmonitortools portable application (for HDD/SSD test) Thats another linux script for hdd testing. 4. LSPCI commands (I configure what combination of lshw/parameters will run) 5. Dmidecode commands (I configure what combination of lshw/parameters will run) Server gets the request from client. Server executes remotely all the above to the client machine and it gets the requested info. Server stores that info in a -xml format in a directory that i will choose.

Several concepts that i cant understand:

How i execute lshw,lspci,dmidecode commands to remote clients. Maybe i have to write a script that connects with ssh or telnet to clients and execute all those commands? What programming language is the best to write script for this job. Python? C? or what? Maybe programming language is not necessary for this? Any ideas how i find information to write such scripts?

Thank you in advance for any answer

Comment: If you have a 48 port switch with one server plugged into it you could only plug in 47 desktops, 46 if you also need to connect that switch to another network.

Comment: Indeed! You are absolutely right. 46 is also fine!

Comment: Welcome to SE and please don't take it personally, but I voted to close this question as too broad.  If you can narrow this down to a single, rational goal I'm sure it would be more well received.  Questions that ask for complete ground-up solutions to complex problems don't usually get much traction here.  However if you can manage to solve most of your problem and then ask about specific hang ups you are having people are usually much more willing to help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should i make a new question? For example:  Script for remotely execution of lshw,lspci,dmidecode.

Comment: For step 2, make the PC boot a customised live-cd or minimal linux distribution image that automatically runs those commands (lshw, etc) and then uploads them to the server (along with the MAC address, which makes a useful semi-unique identifier).   i.e. push rather than pull - you can't get the server to remotely query the PC unless it's running an OS and something to listen for that query and respond appropriately.